# Write buffers to response stream or at end of long running request?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

The following is an ASP.NET Core API running the .NET Framework.  This is one of my MVC controllers.

I have to get data from an external service that only let's me get fairly small buffers of data at a time - I have no control over this.  Let's say I get 500 rows of data per buffer, but my client wants all of the data at once to be formatted as a CSV, so I have to loop and call the external source like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(MyRequest request)
{
    var aggregateResponse = await client.GetDataAsync(request);
    while (aggregateResponse.HasMoreData)
    {
        request.Cookie = aggregateResponse.Cookie;
        var response = await client.GetDataAsync(request);
        //Data is a list of objects containing n number of properties
        aggregateResponse.Data.Concat(response.Data)

        //I need the cookie from the previous response to get the next buffer
        aggregateResponse.Cookie = response.Cookie;
        aggregateResponse.HasMoreData = response.HasMoreData;
    }
    //runs through a generic IEnumerable CSV output formatter (uses reflection)
    return Ok(aggregateResponse.Data);
}
```

Sadly this can take 100-200 loops to get back all of the data (50,000 - 100,000 list items in aggregateResponse.Data), but I don't have much of a choice on that one.

- Would it be more efficient to format every buffer of data into a CSV in the loop and write it to the response stream each time, or better to wait until the end like I'm currently doing? Example:

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get(MyRequest request)

  {
      var response = await client.GetDataAsync(request);
      await Response.WriteAsync(formatBeginningData(response.Data))
      while (request.HasMoreData)
      {
          request.Cookie = aggregateResponse.Cookie;
          response = await client.GetDataAsync(request);
          await Response.WriteAsync(formatData(response.Data))
          request.Cookie = response.Cookie;
          request.HasMoreData = response.HasMoreData;
      }

      return Ok();
  }
  ```
- I'm continuously using async in this method for data calls, but that means threads are going to be switching a heck of a lot of times. Is doing this asynchronously actually giving me a performance decrease? Should it all be synchronous (method signature and data calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be more efficient to format every buffer of data into a CSV in the loop and write it to the response stream each time, or better to wait until the end like I'm currently doing?

You can *stream*, but I wouldn't recommend it unless the data is too big to fit into memory.

The advantages of streaming are that the data doesn't have to fit in memory and that the client can receive it piecemeal.

The disadvantages of streaming are that the HTTP response code must be sent *before* streaming begins, so there is no way to notify the client of errors after the streaming starts. So, if one of the calls to `GetDataAsync` fails, the client would still get a `200 OK`, but one whose data is cut off unexpectedly.

> I'm continuously using async in this method for data calls, but that means threads are going to be switching a heck of a lot of times. Is doing this asynchronously actually giving me a performance decrease? Should it all be synchronous (method signature and data calls)?

No; asynchronous code on ASP.NET Core has the same or fewer thread switches than synchronous code.